# How to convert a String arrayList to a boolean arrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, boolean

I'm using Java 7, I got a list of String from an api as bellow :

```
List = ["ON","OFF"];
```

So I change it to :

```
List = ["true","false"];
```

I want to change the final one to a boolean list as :

```
List = [true,false];
```

This is what I've done :

```
String responseapi = response.asString();
                        responseapi= responseapi.replace("ON", String.valueOf(true));
                        responseapi= responseapi.replace("OFF", "false");
                      ArrayList<String> stats = new ArrayList<>();
                        stats.add(responseapi);
                      ArrayList<Boolean> stats = new ArrayList<>();

                        for(String x:stats){
                            stats1.add(Boolean.parseBoolean(x));
                            System.out.println("hi"+stats1);

                        }
```

The problem is that I' getting :

```
List = [false,false];
```

Comment: What is `response` is that the list?

Comment: it's the response from an API it contains two String "ON" and "OFF"

Comment: Write an example of `response` content, please.

Comment: Another thing, pay attention that you named both `ArrayList` of String and Boolean with the name `stats`.

Comment: it gives the result of the GET request : 200 OK

Comment: You should explain better what you want to obtain. Only convert a list with two string value to a list of two boolean value?

Comment: A couple of answers have already been given that should solve your problem, but I have difficulties to believe that the code you provided is the code you used for your tests: You declare two variables with the same name which should lead to a compile error. You only add one value to the first list but claim, that you end with a result-list with two elements. For the future, please always post the actual code you're using for your tests, otherwise it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the original list you can just use the stream api like this.

This is assuming that your response list is not null and does not contain any null values.

```
List<String> response = ... // {"ON", "OFF", "ON", "ON", "OFF"}
```

---

**For Java 8+:**

```
List<Boolean> booleanList = response.stream()
    .map(s -> "ON".equalsIgnoreCase(s.trim()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// booleanList == {true, false, true, true, false}
```

---

**For pre Java 8:**

```
List<Boolean> booleanList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s : response){
    booleanList.add("ON".equalsIgnoreCase(s.trim()));
}
```

---

I think what ended up being the issue is that your input list didn't have the exact values `"ON"` or `"OFF"`, they may have had spaces around them so `s.trim().equals("ON")` or `s.contains("ON")` gets around that. Also you didn't need to have an `if-else` since you can just add the result of the boolean expression to your boolean list directly.

Comment: is there a solution for JAVA 7 ?

Comment: That would only work on Java 8+ or using StreamSupport

Comment: it returns [false,false]

Comment: @AmalSoltani Edited, trimming the input in case it has spaces around it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as followed:

```
List = { "true", "false" };
final Boolean[] booleanList = Arrays.stream(booleanList)
         .map(Boolean::parseBoolean).toArray(Boolean[]::new);
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the API returns something like:

```
    List<String> apiResponse = Arrays.asList("OFF", "ON", "ON", "OFF");
```

Then it's possible to use stream the result and map the response to a boolean.  For example:

```
    List<Boolean> switches = apiResponse.stream().map(s -> s.equals("ON").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert the list. 
You can use a function like this

```
public ArrayList<Boolean> convertToBooleanList(ArrayList<String> responseArrayList) {
        ArrayList<Boolean> convertedList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        for (String response : responseArrayList) {
            switch (response) {
                case "ON":
                    convertedList.add(true);
                    break;

                case "OFF":
                    convertedList.add(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return convertedList;
}
```

Comment: it return an empty List

Comment: @AmalSoltani If the list is empty, the values in the list is not 'ON' or 'OFF' but something else, e.g. '  ON  '.

Comment: If the input is neither "ON" nor "OFF" exactly then it will be silently ignored and your result list will be a different length than your input list. I would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in the default case. Common boolean parsing returns true if the value matches any of the truthy values, else false. So the only benefit I can see for the switch boilerplate would be to throw an exception when there's not an exact match.

Comment: it worked i done it with for loop :
for(int i = 0 ; i< stats.size();i++){
                            if(stats.get(i).contains("ON")){
                                status.add(true);

                            }
                            else if(stats.get(i).contains("OFF")){
                                status.add(false);

                            }

                        }
                        System.out.println("hi "+status);

                        }
the only problem is that I'm getting [true,true,false] in place of [true,false]

Comment: I didn't want to add it in my answer because I don't know if he will want to throw an exception or just add any other case

Comment: @AmalSoltani So this code with the switch statements didn't actually work? Please check what my answer had.  My `for(String s : response){
    booleanList.add(s != null && "on".equalsIgnoreCase(s.trim()));
}` should have done the trick for you, why was that not accepted?

Comment: @xtratic it does work but why would you add a performance impact if you know that the source is fixed

Comment: @GilGoldzweig His comment above says he used a for loop with if statements, but you use a switch statement. I think his issue was that his input values needed to be trimmed. I know this code would work but only if his input was good, or if you trimmed the input. What performance impact are you referring to?

Comment: Why add the `switch` boilerplate when you know that the source is fixed? If you know the input is definitely going to be "ON" or "OFF" then `for(String s : inputList){ boolList.add("ON".equals(s));}` is much less boilerplate. Your switch statement would likely compile to an `if-else` anyway.